# Do I need Multi-org enabled to use SF data entry in journey builder for a Child BU?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

We are trying to set up an SF data entry in Journey Builder for a child BU. It works in the parent BU which means it is nothing to do with the connection but not for the Child Bu. We are getting the following error "There was a problem retrieving the Integration Status.".

Is this because I don't have Multi-org enabled? If it is not, what else can I do?

Thanks!!

Comment: in Sales Cloud, have you have provided access to your child BU in Marketing cloud connection settings?

Comment: Hi @Maneesh I did

Comment: The user that is used on SFMC's end - does that have access to the BU ? If yes, then try initiating the log and see what error you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need multi org for this. What you need to be aware of is:

1. Integration user in SFMC needs to have access to all the relevant BUs (this is far the most common cause of the issue you are facing). You do this by looking up the user in **Setup > Users > Users**:

[image]

Check the box next to the user and click on **Manage Business Units**. You get to this page, where you need to ensure all relevant associated business units are selected:

[image]

2. Once you have confirmed permissions in SFMC, ensure in Sales Cloud, that all the relevant BUs are enabled in the integration configuration:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Lukas Lunow,

How to check the first point? I checked the second one and it is ticked.

Comment: @Mrquestion - sorry for the late reply. I have updated my answer to help you. Let me know if you managed to get this to work.

Comment: @Marquestion, can you confirm you were able to get a child BU to use SF Data Entry in JB? Are you able to also have Salesforce Update Contact Activities in the child BU? (I assume both BUs are connected to the same org?) Did you have to enable Multi-org to achieve this?

Comment: @LukasLunow, are you sure we don't need Multi-org enabled? From this doc. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_scenario_examples.htm&type=5 it looks like we do. We are looking for the right solution to connect Multiple BUs to one SF org, while having the possibility to use SF Canvas Activities, SF Data Entry, and Decision splits in all BUs. What would the solution be?

Comment: @LimeWeb I have configured countless multi-BU setups, with single org connector, and Sales Cloud JB activities work normally across all child BUs

Comment: @LukasLunow, THANK YOU! that's VERY helpful. Have been researching this in the last 72 hours, and there is no clear answer in the StackExchange and old (2018,2019) data suggests otherwise. One can even find (now outdated) blog posts about how to workaround (copy Synced DEs to child BUs via SQL). We'll try to go without activating Multi-org from the beginning, as you suggest.

Comment: @LimeWeb the only use case requiring multi org is when you need to connect multiple Salesforce orgs. Keep in mind - JB events are not related to your synced DEs, and you will need to sync them to child BUs using SQL, as described. Verify your BU settings in connector config in your org, so you are sure to allow communication to multiple BUs.

Comment: @LukasLunow, hmmmm.... what you are saying is that we don't have 2 Objects configurations (one per BU), so we can't have a different Boolean field on Salesforce Objects (e.g. Contacts) to filter which Contacts sync to BU1 vs. BU2? so everything goes to Parent BU, and filtered by SQL? Wouldn't Multiple-Org resolve this as described here? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_scenario_examples.htm&type=5 (Second architecture shows BUs are independent)

Comment: @LimeWeb this is correct. best practice is indeed to use SQL to filter synced records to child BUs, without multi-org

Comment: @LukasLunow, thanks again! To my understanding both configurations - with or w/o MultiOrg - will get us the results (be able to use SF activities in Parent+Child BUs' Journey Builder). see EliotHarper 's reply here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228780/using-sales-cloud-attributes-in-decision-split-activities-within-a-child-bu/231408?noredirect=1#comment487836_231408

Curious, why avoid using multiOrg as best practice? Without multi-org, the maintenance to SQL would be costly (every time we sync a new field). PS. Our org has ~300K contacts. What's the downside of multi org?

Comment: @EliotHarper, any thoughts on the config. / solution proposed by Lukas above - without using multi-org? If, with multi-org, each BU has its own config of Objects (fields that sync on each of the SF Objects, boolean to pre-filter, etc.) and we don't need SQL activities to copy to other BUs (which introduce maintenance and lag to child BUs) - the only downside I can think of - is the double amount of API calls from SF >> MC ? Is this a real concern? What am I missing?

Comment: @LimeWeb - if you instead of SQL utilise filtered data extensions, these will automatically receive the new fields as they are added to Synchronised Data Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I had that error when I was logged in as a user which was not 'Salesforce integrated'. Once I integrated my user, the error disappeared.